# Including variable data with ng-class expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am re-building a clients site in Angular and part of that is re-building he way he lists his properties.  In the interim, I have created a controller using $http to pull the variable data from an external json file and then with ng-repeat, populated the page.

Everything is working as expected, but I have another feature I am trying to solve.  Some of the properties are either under contract or sold and I would like to place a corner ribbon over the image based off a setting in the json variable. I was able to get it working slightly using ng-class...see my code below.

```
    <div class="row outer" ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="featured-block">
                    <div ng-class="{ featured : listing.featured == 1}">
                        <div class="ribbon ribbon-red">
                            <div class="banner">
                                <div class="text">Under Contract</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <img class="img-responsive listings-img" ng-src="{{listing.imageUrl}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

As you can see, it works but the Under Contract is hard coded into the page so even though an image with a variable of featured == 1 is set, the hard coded "Under Contract" shows in every image.

Ideally I would like to be able to dynamically show various ribbons based on a variable condition, but would be happy enough to just display the 'Under Contract' only if the variable feature == 1 is set in the json file.  I hope this makes some sense.  Thank you for your help.  Here is a screen-shot to show what ribbon is displayed based on the above code - I can't insert image here, but I hosted the image here http://studiorooster.com/corbett-ng.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Like :

```
<div class="ribbon ribbon-red" ng-show="listing.featured == 1">
     <div class="banner">
          <div class="text">Under Contract</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.  Right under my nose.  Thank You! Is there a simple way of adding featured == 2 to show a different ribbon class?

Comment: Yw. Try something like : `ng-class="{ 'featured' : listing.featured == 1, 'quitefeatured': listing.featured == 2}"`

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is a simple thing to with angular. I've made a jsfiddle for you to mess around with. It uses ng-class as well as ng-show to hide banners as well as change the featured class using ng-show. If you have many classes I would suggest `ng-class` but I guess this depends on the project and how unique the markup is.

http://jsfiddle.net/27rxqeLL/1/

Comment: @Ram and Pedro Thank you both for the input, I'll mess around with it and report back which worked in my case.

Comment: @Ram and Pedro - I used a combination of both your solutions and everything is working brilliantly. I added my final code that worked in my original question.  Thank you again, both of you.

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL CODE SOLUTION**
Thank you @Ram and @Pedro for your help.  So others can benefit, here is the final code that combines both of your suggestions.

```
<div class="row outer" ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="featured-block">
                <div ng-class="{ contracted : listing.featured == 1, sold: listing.featured == 2, reduced: listing.featured == 3}">
                    <div class="ribbon ribbon-red" ng-show="listing.featured == 1">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <div class="text">Under Contract</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ribbon ribbon-blue" ng-show="listing.featured == 2">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <div class="text">Sold</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ribbon ribbon-orange" ng-show="listing.featured == 3">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <div class="text">Reduced</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <img class="img-responsive listings-img" ng-src="{{listing.imageUrl}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```